# How are these two questions the same?

Tags: discussion

My question, [How does the Anglican Church defend its legitimacy due to the circumstances of its founding?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/89199/how-does-the-anglican-church-defend-its-legitimacy-due-to-the-circumstances-of-i) has been marked as the same as this question [How do Anglicans, who recognize apostolic succession, trace theirs?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34876/how-do-anglicans-who-recognize-apostolic-succession-trace-theirs) How are these questions the same? One (mine) asks about how a church defends their legitimacy under the circumstances by which they were founded. The other asks how the Anglican Church traces the apostolic succession. Are they the same because apostolic succession gives a church credibility? If so, does that make them the same question? It seems that in that case the 2nd question would only serve as an answer to the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, I don't think they're duplicates your logic is sounds.

One of the privileges (or curses) of a gold badge in a tag (especially when the tag is [catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism) ) is that it gives you mod-hammer level powers to close questions as dupes whether you want to or not.  I can see informing you of that question, but I can't see closing it

So if Geremia votes to close a question with [catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism) as a duplicate, it just gets closed as a duplicate immediately, as if a moderator had closed it (which is also immediate).  Now, I don't think this is particularly fair since the subject of the question was actually Anglicanism. Moderators can't VTC questions like regular privileged users can, the idea, I guess, is that there's enough privileged users out there to help in moderations and few enough moderators not to cause any trouble.

I'd suggest flagging a one-vote close by a mod or anyone that you disagree with, doesn't necessarily need to go to meta to get a second look.

Comment: Does that mean as soon as someone has this privilege, that person doesn't have the option to mark as duplicate without immediately closing before others also voted close? So no way of "lowering" their vote power? That's terrible! Does that mean in order to gather community feedback, that person has to wait for other votes or open a discussion here on Meta?

Comment: @kut that's entirely correct.  Great power = Great responsibility and all that.

Comment: Sweet, how do I get a gold badge so I can close all the questions?

Comment: @jaredad7 answer popular Catholicism questions before Ken does instead of ones nobody gives a rip about (j/k stellar work lately!) .   https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/badges/138/catholicism

Comment: "before Ken does" is a tall order